# TCP Server receives data slower than rate at which data is being sent

Tags: android, c, sockets, tcp

I am facing a weird problem. My TCP server has a print line that prints out
the buffer value whenever I receive data from the TCP client.

My TCP Client will be able to send in the buffer, in double values through bytes. On Server receive, the bytes will be received and I output the value on the print line.

For example:

```
TCP Client send: "0.25"
TCP Server receive: "0.25"
```

However, because my client is able to control the speed at which data is being sent out, sometimes the server receive values concatenated together when I send out values too fast.

For example:

```
TCP Client send: "0.27"
TCP Client send: "0.53"
TCP Client send: "0.91"
TCP Server receive: "0.270.530.90"
```

But what I would expect is this:

```
TCP Server receive: "0.27"
TCP Server receive: "0.53"
TCP Server receive: "0.90"
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Here is my sending of data on the client side on my android

```
LoginActivity.getSocket().getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(multiplier).getBytes());
```

And here is my receiving of data on the server side.

```
while(1){
        nread = sl_Recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0);
        buffer[nread] = '\0';
        if(nread==0){
            UART_PRINT("Connection Lost!\n\r");
            UART_PRINT("Listening again...\n\r");
            clientSocket = sl_Accept(welcomeSocket, ( struct SlSockAddr_t *)&serverStorage, (SlSocklen_t*)&addr_size);
            if(clientSocket<0){
                sl_Close(welcomeSocket);
                sl_Close(clientSocket);
                ASSERT_ON_ERROR(ACCEPT_ERROR);
            }
            UART_PRINT("Successfully Connected!!!\n\r");
        }
        else if(nread==-1){
            ASSERT_ON_ERROR(RECV_ERROR);
        }
        else{
            if(atof(buffer)>=0 && atof(buffer)<=1){
                UART_PRINT("Data Received: %s\n\r",buffer);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Looks very strange. At worst the receiver will concatenate the data received, so would receive `"0.20.50.9"`

Comment: Please provide  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There must be some bug in the (multithreading?) code you didn't show.

Comment: You should read about how TCP protocol work...

Comment: TCP buffers data to avoid sending small packets. Use TCP_NODELAY

Comment: @stark There is no guarantee that that will provide what the OP is expecting.

Comment: 'Double values and in string format' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: It isn't possible that you receive "0.2.5.9" , but you might very well receive "0.20.50.9" . TCP doesn't deal with messages or delimited data - it just provides a stream of data. A client doing several send() call could be received with just one recv() call, or vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, i will re-edit my post to show the real output values i got from the program tomorrow. I have just left the office. And posted this based on my very vague memory of the output i got

Comment: Is your problem just that you aren't sending newlines?

Comment: Hi all, I have edited my post, do have a look. Yes my data are all concatenated when I print it out. I  am sending newlines perhaps sometimes it doesn't get sent through?

Comment: You are not sending newlines.

Comment: Your edit continues to make no sense. There are three possibilities: -1, 0, and > 0. You need to test them all. != 0 is not correct. You have not implemented `sizeof buffer -1` either. `\n\r` is not a correct line terminator. You have them back to front.

Comment: @EJP oh okay, so what you meant is I do something like this? string.valueOf(multiplier+"\r\n") ? Woah, the entire sample code for my server device uses \n\r so I was just following the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is not possible unless you have coding bugs, but your expectations are misplaced. TCP goes to a lot of trouble to optimize network usage, and it provides a byte stream to the application, not a message service. Any expectation you may have that it will treat one send as one message and preserve that message boundary when receiving is completely without foundation.

**EDIT** Problems with your code:

1. You are ignoring end of stream and errors. You need to check `nread` for both 0 and -1.
2. You also need to ensure that adding the trailing null doesn't overrun the buffer, which would be best done by using `sizeof buffer -1` as the length in the `recv()` call.
3. You aren't separating the numbers when you send them, so if they get coalesced, as they will, you get wrong values.

> I am sending newlines

No you aren't:

```
LoginActivity.getSocket().getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(multiplier).getBytes());
```

There are no newlines there, only the bytes of a `String` value of (apparently) a `double`.

Comment: Hmm, yes i may have coding bugs. I will re-edit my post to include my codes for sending and receiving data as well as the output of my program once I reach work tomorrow!

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post to include my codes, do have a look! I'm not very good with sockets yet so I may be having a bad practice in receiving or sending data I guess

Comment: I have edited my post, as following pointers 1 and 2 you have provided. For number 3, what do you mean by separating the numbers?

Comment: You are sending "0.27" immediately followed by "0.53", and because there is no separation, and no message boundaries, you can receive that as "0.270.53", and who knows how `atof()` is going to interpret that? Add a space or a comma or a line terminator or something, and *parse* your input. Your edit makes absolutely no sense. -1 means an *error,* on which you should call `perror()` and break; 0 means end of stream, on which you should break; and a *positive* number means data.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the post. What do you mean by parsing my input?

Comment: At the rate which you've taken up my previous suggestions I am afraid we will all be old and grey before you understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I was pretty sure either the socket on client side was having delays in sending data, or the server side having delays in receiving data.

I added this line of code to my client side on my android.

```
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

And my program works as what I have expected. Not sure if there will be any negative effects for using that, but I didn't seem to face any problems after that.